# How to make a executable blender file into debian(.deb)

Tags: software-center, games, debian, executable, blender

I have made a game(1.5a release version) in Blender and I want to make it debian(so evryone can install it trought Software center with .deb file). Who can tell me, how to do that? And also I would like to know how to make it non-open-source.

Answer (score 0):

[To export to a standalone player](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Blender_Player) you enable the "Save as Game Engine Runtime" addon, then File -> Export -> Save as Game Engine Runtime

From 2.72 there is also a [new addon](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Game_Engine/Publishing) that should help creating multiple binaries on one machine.

There isn't much choice with [licensing](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Licensing), and you won't get legal advise on stackexchange, you will need to find your own legal counsel. To highlight a point from the wiki page, exporting to a standalone player is considered a derivative work and must be licensed as GPL.

Comment: But I want to make my game installable with Software center using .deb file and I want it to appear in Dash after install. Also I would like to know how to change it's runtime logo from blender to my own...

Comment: I have 2 questions:  * Who can help me packing Blender Runtime Game file into .deb file. * Who can tell me how to make Runtime Game file for Windows trought Linux computer...